# Alternative to standard MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli, mariadb

Yes, I'm yet another person to as this annoying question... but I'm not convinced thus far, so here goes!

I'm working on a project that relies heavily on MySQL and PHP, it uses the standard mysql functions that come packaged with the php/mysql/setup and thus has no "extra cool things".

Should I change the engine to a drop in replacement like MariaDB or something like that, or just use mysqli rather? Or something like PDO perhaps?

Any alternatives would be great to know as well as what is ultimately "better" when it comes to overall performance and usability.

Comment: I suggest you to migrate to PDO. Its simple, secure and amazing. Read more here http://a2znotes.blogspot.in/2014/09/introduction-to-pdo.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PDO, because it doesn't only support MySQL. Whereas MySQLI, obviously, only supports MySQL. If you use PDO you will much more easily make the transition from MySQL to, for instance, PostgreSQL.

[A great reference on PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was hoping to get more options though, not just the things I already mentioned..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rewrite the entire database logic I recommend you to give a try to [Doctrine2 ORM](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html). It is really powerful and handle a lot of DBM (through PDO or custom connectors in order to support MongoDB in example).

If you don't, PDO might be your best option.